# Changing input language has no effect

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have two input types: Russian & English. When I change language, I see that the icon changes, but nothing actually  happens; I still type with English letters. When I open the keyboard layout chart I see Russian letters, but I can type only English letters.

I've tried changing input method but it doesn't help.

Does anybody have any idea about this issue?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (with Unity). I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to switch layouts, but clicking the panel icon doesn't do anything different.

Comment: same as [Switching language with keyboard shortcut in GNOME is ineffective](//askubuntu.com/q/307886)? can you change language by clicking the panel icon?

Comment: Which shortcut do you use? And which desktop? Where do you set the shortcut?

Comment: shift+control+space
Ubuntu 16.04
I set it in the Text Entry settings

Comment: Also, switching from panel also does not make any effect

Comment: In addition, I have Unity desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed other environment(Gnome) and now everything works fine